# Place Page Header Under Group Header In Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Can I place page header under  group header in crystal reports?
A group can print on multiple pages.
I want to repeat some heading on each page, but have the group heading always print on first page of that group.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'detail section heading'.

Comment: You cannot reorder groups, but you could split the group header into two sections and have one repeat on each page.